# Generate apk file inside smartphone

Tags: android, apache-cordova

I have written code for an android application using ApacheCordova. Now i want to generate apk file from that source code inside an android smartphone. Is it possible ?

Comment: do you want to compile your app on the phone or you just want to retrieve the apk of an already installed app?

Comment: i want to compile app on the phone ?

Comment: I was asking you actually, you cant ask back xD

Comment: i have used "?" sign mistakenly in that comment . Sorry for that. What i actually want to know is - i have written a code using apache cordova. Now can i generate apk file if i put the whole source code in an android smartphone?

 i want to build apk file inside an android os ? - is it clear to you now ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Shareit](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.lenovo.anyshare.gps&hl=en). When you share your app through ShareIt, the shareit would generate .apk file and send to other user. Thus you get your .apk file.

Comment: What i actually want to know is - i have written a code using apache cordova. Now can i generate apk file if i put the whole source code in an android smartphone? i want to build apk file inside an android os ? - is it clear to you now ?

Answer (score 0):

[Install this app and you can extract an apk file from an android application, click here](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ext.ui)

Comment: What i actually want to know is - i have written a code using apache cordova. Now can i generate apk file if i put the whole source code in an android smartphone? i want to build apk file inside an android os ? - is it clear to you now ?